# How to delete conditional formatting from a "dragged" cell

Tags: excel, drag-and-drop, conditional-formatting

I have a cell with conditional formatting.
I drag that cell to the one on its right. As a result, the value gets copied and the conditional formatting too.
Then I remove the conditional formatting from that second cell, but as a result, the conditional formatting of my first cell gets deleted too.

How can I delete the conditional formatting of a dragged cell without deleting the conditional formatting of the original cell?

Is this a bug?

Comment: I suggest to use copy and special pasting instead of dragging. You can paste only values if you wish, so your conditional formatting won't change. Second option would be editing the area of the CF rule after dragging, using the wizard itself. But to be honest, check special pasting. [Paste options](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/paste-options-8ea795b0-87cd-46af-9b59-ed4d8b1669ad)

Comment: Select the cells you want to remove conditional format and clear formats from `HOME` tab `Editing` section.

Comment: @Dominique Glad to know. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two ways.

1. Copy data and paste as values.
2. If you drag cells then value and formats will be copied. After dragging select cells you want to remove format. Then From `Home` tab `Editing` section clear formats only. See the below screenshot for better understanding.

[image]